# The tabBarController is not displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

i want to make `tabbarcontroller` programatically. The `tabBarController` is not displayed in the page. can anyone tell that whts going wrong.and can we make more than one `tabbarcontroller` in an application

```
ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    report=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    View1 *template=[[View1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil];
    View2 *acc=[[View2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];
    View3 *four=[[View3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"View3" bundle:nil];
    View4 *five=[[View4 alloc]initWithNibName:@"View4" bundle:nil];   

    nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:report];
    nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:template];
    nav3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: acc];
    nav4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:four];
     nav5=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:five];

    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" image:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"singleicon.png"] tag:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reports" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doubleicon.png"] tag:1];
    UITabBarItem *item2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" New " image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clockicon.png"] tag:2];
    UITabBarItem *item3=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"four" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dependenticon.png"] tag:3];
    UITabBarItem *item4=[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"five" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolicon.png"] tag:4];

    nav1.tabBarItem = item;
    nav2.tabBarItem = item1;
    nav3.tabBarItem = item2;
    nav4.tabBarItem=item3;
    nav5.tabBarItem=item4;

    //[item1 setBadge:@"25"];
    self.tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5,nil]];

    self.report = self.tabBarController;
  // [self.report makeKeyAndVisible];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: follow my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856933/tabbar-in-second-view/13857070#13857070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just did this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
     self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5,nil]];
     self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

**UPDATE:**

also for Hide and Show the `UITabBar` then use bellow code ..

just put this methods in `AppDelegate.m` file and when you want to hide tabbar at that time just create `AppDelegate` object and call bellow `hideTabBar` method

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    int height = 480;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x,view.frame.origin.y, 320, 436)];
        }
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    int height = 436;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {

        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, height, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];            
        } 
        else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, height)];
        }
    }    

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: sir i have done this in viewController.m not in appdelegate so why i will use window

Comment: @VivekSehrawat if you want to set tabbarcontroller as a rootview controller then you can set like this just create object of AppDelegate and write appDelegate.window insted of self.window

Comment: i want to show tabbarcontroller only on specfic pages so how can i do this..?

Comment: @VivekSehrawat try my updated code may you can get some idea from this

Comment: Don't use 480 as the height, iPhone 5 has a different height. Use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height instead

Comment: @NikitaP yes right dear and here also change the height and width with current orientation ... i just give the Idea or code which i use and complete the task dear.. anyway thanx .. :)

Comment: [appDelegate showTabBar]; xcode is not accepting this..how to call appdelegate method then

Comment: @VivekSehrawat AppDelegate *appDelegate(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [appDelegate hideTabbar:self.tabBarController]; try this dude..

Comment: @VivekSehrawat set height int height = 436; try and also change this value with your requirement.. i just implement this idea and work well dude..

Comment: this is not working can u tell me ur email id that i can send u my file

Answer (score 1):

put all the coding in the action of the button and push the `tabBarController` like that:-

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `UITabBarController` programmatically, then you need to add your `tabbarcontroller`  to your `ViewController`. you need to use this line,

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: No, this is not the way to go. Paras Joshi has the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tabBarController in view you have missed the one line