# Tabbar in Second View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbar

I have an activation page in my app, which is mandatory for every user to activate the app.
Once the app is activated, the user moves to the tabbed bar view.

I have created a tabbed bar application, where from my activationView on click of button I am trying to call the tab bar, I am getting an entire black screen.

```
- (IBAction)moveToActivateView:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    appDelegate.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey make your tabBarController's property in appDelegate and assign all ViewController there then call your tabBarController from yourViewController

**in AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

**in AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self makeTabBar];

    [self addInitialVIew];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}  


-(void)makeTabBar
{    
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.delegate=self;
    FirstViewController *firstVC =[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];    

    UINavigationController *firstNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
    firstNC.tabBarItem.title=@"Profile";
    firstVC.tabBarController.tabBar.tag = 0;


    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *SecondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC];    
    SecondNavController.tabBarItem.title = @"Search";
    secondVC.tabBarController.tabBar.tag = 1;


    NSArray *viewControllers =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:firstNC,SecondNavController, nil];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];   
}

-(void) addInitialVIew
{    
    InitialViewController *initialViewController = [[InitialViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"InitialViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:ViewController];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
}
```

Now in `InitialViewController` you can add yourTabBar and remove `InitialViewController`

```
- (IBAction)switchToTabBarBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegte =(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [[[appdelegte navigationController] view]removeFromSuperview];

    [[appdelegte window]addSubview:[[appdelegte tabBarController]view]];

    [[appdelegte tabBarController]setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

And Follow my answer

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460013/remove-uitabbar-controller/12460244#12460244)

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize that your local varialbe `tabBarController` is not identical but sort of hides the property `self.tabBarController`? You create a new `UITabBarCotnroller` and assign it to your local variable `tabBarController`, which is accessible from this method only. Then you manipulate (add newly created view controllers) etc to `self.tabBarController`. `Self.tabBarController` could easily be nil here or anything else. But it is not the very `UITabBarController` that you just created.

And it is `self.tabBarController` (so probably nil) what you assign to the window as `rootViewController`.

You do add the `tabBarController's` view as subview to self.view. Besides that I do not know what self acutally is, I don't think is it really nessessary to manually add the tabBar's view as subview. Setting the root view controller (properly) should be enough

Answer (score 0):

You want to create dynamic tabbar application to resolve your problem. So you just create the view based application. in the view controller viewdidload method put these code

```
tabbar1 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    artist_tab_obj = [[artist_tab alloc] initWithNibName:@"artist_tab" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: artist_tab_obj] autorelease];
    tabItem1.title=@"Artist";
    tabItem1.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon1.png"];
    music_tab_obj = [[music_tab alloc] initWithNibName:@"music_tab" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: music_tab_obj] autorelease];

    tabItem2.title=@"Music";
    tabItem2.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon2.png"];

    shout_tab_obj = [[shout_tab alloc] initWithNibName:@"shout_tab" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem3 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: shout_tab_obj] autorelease];

    tabItem3.title=@"Shout";
    tabItem3.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon3.png"];
    schedule_tab_obj = [[schedule_tab alloc] initWithNibName:@"schedule_tab" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem4 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: schedule_tab_obj] autorelease];

    tabItem4.title=@"Schedule";
    tabItem4.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon4.png"];
    follow_tab_obj = [[follow_tab alloc] initWithNibName:@"follow_tab" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem5 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: follow_tab_obj] autorelease];
    tabItem5.title=@"Follower";
    tabItem5.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon5.png"];


    tabbar1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem1, tabItem2,tabItem3,tabItem4,tabItem5,nil];
```

In user acceptation is yes button action call this code.

```
[self.view insertSubview:tabbar1.view belowSubview: artist_tab_obj.view];
tabbar1.selectedIndex=1;
[self presentModalViewController:tabbar1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have tried implementing your code, I am getting an error
 `Property 'viewControllers' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'` Please can you share the corresponding h file also.