# DidFinishLoading view change

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uiwindow

I have a login screen view and 5 tabs in the app.I want when I done with the LoginScreen and it should move to the Tabs views(5) .for this once Login Task is done,I have to remove the view and add the another view controller of the tab..how to do this...

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];


self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

like this way I moves to the login view...now how to remove after completion of login and move to the `tab1,tab2,tab3,tab4,tab5`

Comment: find this link my answer may be help to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13857343/510814

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856933/tabbar-in-second-view/13857070#13857070

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you add your `firstViewController` as subView to your `addDelegate.window`, then on `buttonClick` you can remove your `navController` and add `tabBarController` to `appDelegate.window`

Follow my answer for better result  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856933/tabbar-in-second-view/13857070#13857070)

Answer (score 2):

You can create the following methods in you AppDelegate to switch between 2 navigation controllers.

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

+ (void)showLogin {
    AppDelegate *selfInstance = [self sharedDelegate];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    selfInstance.window.rootViewController = nav;

}

+ (void)showTabs {
    AppDelegate *selfInstance = [self sharedDelegate];

    self.viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController2];
    selfInstance.window.rootViewController = nav;
}
```

Your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method should then look like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if( isLoggedIn ){
        [AppDelegate showLogin];
    } else {
        [AppDelegate showTabs];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Then from anywhere in you app you can do:

```
[AppDelegate showTabs];
```

Let me know if you need help implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `UITabBarController` as your initial view. There you can check if you need to log-in, or if you auto log-in. If you need to go to the login screen, just use a modal segue to display the login view and dismiss it when login is done.

Comment: hey whets this modal seque ..I am not aware of this ...How to use this

Comment: @Christien you should check out [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) about basic storyboard. In this part 2 you can find what is the modal segue about.