# No tabbaritem selected in UITabbarController in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I want to load a `tabBarController` with no `tabBar` selected. Actually each `tabBarItem` corresponds to a certain  `ViewController`.But I have a view "Success" and it doesnot belong to any tabBarItem.So when Successview appears then I need a `tabBarController` with three `tabBarItems` (Search,Settings) need to appear and when any tabbaritem is then selected then corresponding ViewController should appear and SuccesView should disappear.
Gone through google and find out this but couldn't make it working.

In SuccessView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// UIlabels and UITextFields loads

SuccessView *defaultView = [[SuccessView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SuccessView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:nil];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:defaultView];

    SearchView *first = [[SearchView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:nil];
    first.title=@"Search";

    Settings *second=[[Settings alloc]initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    second.title=@"Settings";

    NSArray *viewArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:first,second, nil];

    tabbarController=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabbarController setViewControllers:viewArray animated:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:tabbarController animated:NO];
}
```

But I dont find any tabbarController added to SuccessView.Where I m going wrong?

Comment: just hide your tabBar at successView..

Comment: What I didnt get u ?Can u please breifly explain

Comment: just follow ma answer you will understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856933/tabbar-in-second-view/13857070#13857070

Comment: no what i mean is it should show successpage and on that page itself it should show tabbaritems but none of them selected and success page wont be any of the tabbar item ..So i need this .In ur code it directly redirects to tabbarcontroller without showing Successpage.How can I modify it?

Comment: have you tried @Dalee's code?

Comment: @arizah - this code will do the same(i.e. you can add the tabbar on the success page with none of the tabbar items clicked)..you can write this in your viewDidLoad method...let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even i had the same situation i used `UITabbar` and tabbar items instead of `UITabBarController` because `UITabBarController` expects a current view from any of the tabbar items placed... Here's the code..This should get you going:)

```
 UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(your frame)];   
  NSMutableArray  *tabBarItemsArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"artist" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"artist-tab.png"] tag:1];//assigning the title name and image

    [tabBarItem1 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0/255.0  green:60.0/255.0 blue:109.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//set the color when the tabbar appears

    [tabBarItem1 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];//sets the color when the tabbar is selected

     UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music-tab.png"] tag:2];

    [tabBarItem2 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0/255.0  green:60.0/255.0 blue:109.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [tabBarItem2 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

            [tabBarItemsArray addObject:tabBarItem1];
            [tabBarItemsArray addObject:tabBarItem2];
            tabBar.items = tabBarItemsArray;
            tabBar.delegate = self;

         [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

Make sure you add the delegate `UITabBarDelegate` in your header file to implement this method

```
   - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
        NSLog(@"Tabbar selected itm %d",item.tag); 
   // here you can call your view based on tab click you can try using switch statements here based on item.tag
       }
```

Hope this answers your question and helps:)

Also,we can customize the `UITabbar` with an image...do let me know..i will post the code in here if you want.

Comment: you are looking like Santa Claus..:) nice..are you from?

Comment: Well im a newbie in SO...I thought if it works he will accept the answer..i guess its only way to understand whether the solution worked or no..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21367/discussion-between-rajneesh071-and-dalee-davis)

Comment: superb Dalee .U got me going .Thank u