# Bring Tab bar back after using navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, tabbar

I have an app that based on Tab Bar combined with navigation bar.
In the navigation bar i have a button that takes me to another page which I want to hide the tab bar. When i trying to back to the main view through a button (Not back bar button, regular one) i can't bring the Tab Bar back. 
I did try :  `xxxxx.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =NO;`

Here is some of my code:

In main view:

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
 UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:buttonTitle
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(goToCreateEvent)]; 




-(void)goToCreateEvent{
     UIViewController *targetViewController;
     NSString *viewControllerName = @"CreateAnEventViewController";
     targetViewController = [[NSClassFromString(viewControllerName) alloc]   initWithNibName:viewControllerName bundle:nil];
     targetViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES; //Hides the tab bar
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];

 }
```

In the other view:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
 {
    [summary resignFirstResponder];
    [agenda resignFirstResponder];

    FeedViewController *aboutViewCont = [[FeedViewController alloc] init];

    aboutViewCont.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =NO; //trying to bring back the tab bar

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:aboutViewCont animated:NO];

  }
```

Thanks!
Yossi

Comment: Why you are not passing nibname for FeedViewController ??

Comment: There is no nib file for this class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply solve it:
 [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm having the similar problem there. I tried your solution which unfortunately didn't help out. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

in `viewWillAppear:` method of `FeedViewController` set `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `NO` like bellow..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Try out this one also..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGRect r = self.tabBarController.view.frame;
    r.size.height +=self.tabBarController.tabbar.frame.size.height;
    self.tabBarController.view.frame = r;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); //for iPhone portrait
}
```

use this above methods in your `FeedViewController` class and also just comment this bellow line from your code..

```
targetViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;//comment this..
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help :(

Comment: oh ok then wait i will update answer which is very simple.. :)

Comment: @Yossi see my this answer for Hide and show navigationbar.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929951/how-to-hide-the-title-bartop-bar-in-iphone-from-a-view/12932214#12932214 try like that code for hide the tabbar

Comment: I think i should change somthing in my appDelegete but i don't know what

Comment: @Yossi if you want to do globle code for Hide and show the Tabbar the see my answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856184/the-tabbarcontroller-is-not-displayed/13856325#13856325 create your Tabbar and hide and show with **AppDelegate** class :) hope it will helpful to you...

Comment: The hide() works great, the show() not working :(. Thanks anyway

Comment: This was my solution: [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];